# Gerar uma lista de frases ordenada pelo arraySort() em js

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando criar uma lista de frases ordenada alfabeticamente utilizando o arraySort() em JS, porém utilizando o código abaixo, retorna uma frase duplicada. Alguma ideia de como fazer diferente?

```
//Cria lista de textos

var lista = [];

lista.push( "Amanhã vou comprar um carro." );
lista.push( "Está nevando no Canadá." );
lista.push( "Quem fez o tema?" );
lista.push( "Antes tarde do que nunca." );
lista.push( "Você não pode fazer isso." );
lista.push( "Perdi minha carteira ontem." );


function arraySort( a, b ){
    lista.sort( );
} 
var retorno = lista.sort( arraySort );
console.log( retorno );

/*  
**Retorno:**  
[ 'Amanhã vou comprar um carro.',  
  'Está nevando no Canadá.',  
  'Está nevando no Canadá.',  
  'Perdi minha carteira ontem.',  
  'Quem fez o tema?',  
  'Você não pode fazer isso.' ]
*/
```

---

Se eu utilizar sem o function, retorna correto:

```
var retorno = lista.sort( );
console.log( retorno );
```

Comment: O problema começa no sortCeption. Você está a fazer um `sort` dentro de outro `sort`

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está a fazer um `sort` dentro de outro `sort`:

```
function arraySort( a, b ){
    lista.sort( );
//         ^---- e dentro da função de ordenação chama sort de novo
} 

var retorno = lista.sort( arraySort );
//                   ^--- começa por chamar o ordenar aqui
```

Se pretende fazer uma ordenação normal basta chamar o `sort` normalmente, como indicou na própria pergunta:

```
lista.sort( );
```

É relevante também mencionar que o `sort` altera a lista diretamente, e por isso o retorno é a própria lista que foi ordenada. Ou seja, não retorna uma nova copia ordenada e sim altera a original.

A função serve para poder definir formas diferentes de comparar. Pode por exemplo ordenar os textos de forma inversa com a função de comparação utilizando [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) para comparar as strings:

```
function arraySort( a, b ){
    return b.localeCompare(a);
}
```

Ao passo que se fosse `a.localeCompare(b)` ja daria a ordenação a-z.

Veja o resultado dessa função de comparação no seu código:

```js
//Cria lista de textos
 var lista = [];

lista.push( "Amanhã vou comprar um carro." );
lista.push( "Está nevando no Canadá." );
lista.push( "Quem fez o tema?" );
lista.push( "Antes tarde do que nunca." );
lista.push( "Você não pode fazer isso." );
lista.push( "Perdi minha carteira ontem." );

function arraySort( a, b ){
    return b.localeCompare(a);
} 

var retorno = lista.sort( arraySort );
console.log( retorno );
```